# Variable Importance Intepretation for GLM

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, h2o

I'm having a confusion and can't find any answer from the docs.ai that H2O Team provided.

I'm creating a summary from my glm and receive a variable importance table. But i can't understand what is relative importance, scale importance, and percentage. can anyone explain it to me?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The relative importance is based on the coefficients, the scaled importance is the relative importance scaled between 0 and 1. You can see the normalized coefficients for comparison by using `h2o.coef_norm()`.